# How to scroll with wheel while dragging in JTable and JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, scala

I am using scala.swing, but a solution for Java Swing is also applicable to scala.swing.
Therefore I open this question as a Java Swing question.

I have JTable with TransferHandler in JScrollPane.
Usually, the table can scroll with mouse wheel motion.
While dragging, however, the scroll pane does not move with mouse wheel.

The user can scroll by moving cursor to the top or the bottom of the pane(auto scroll),
but auto scroll is slow, so I want to provide usual mouse functionality.

I tried to capture mouse wheel event in JTable.
When not dragging, it receives MouseWheelMove event, but while dragging, it receives nothing.
My guess is that mouse wheel event is delivered to something related to TransferHandler, not to JTable.

How to detect mouse wheel motion while dragging?
Any other method is welcome, as far as my aim is achieved.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to drag and scroll at the same time in any program.

Comment: Does Any program mean any Java program?  It is possible in some web UIs written with JS.

Comment: I guess it's OS specific: on my win box wheel has no effect in any app I tried (Explorer f.i. as _the_ native reference program)

Comment: I would agree with the comments above and say that if your users need to do this then you should redesign your UI.

Comment: I cannot use such action in Windows XP Explorer as kleopatra reports, but I can in Chrome on Mac, Windows and Finder on Mac. It is not OS specific, just Explorer (and other apps) does not support such behavior. To make sure, my intention is to drag a row on the table, move it up or down, then drop.  In this motion, autoscroll is not enough responsive, I want to provide mouse wheel support. I'm not sure what is so weird in my UI design. Such motion is common among an application with large list (e.g. task management tool). Let me know more.

Comment: If it is possible in Chrome or Finder, then I doubt it is intended behaviour (but maybe I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

It seems (at least on OS X), that the wheel events are buffered and dispatched only after the DnD gesture is complete. Here is my try:

```
import javax.swing._

val d = Array.fill(1000)(Array[AnyRef]((math.random * 1000).toInt.toString))
val t = new JTable(d, Array[AnyRef]("A")) {
  override def processMouseWheelEvent(e: java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent): Unit = {
    println(s"Wheel: ${e.getID}")
    super.processMouseWheelEvent(e)
  }
  def enableEventsP(e: Long): Unit = enableEvents(e)
}
t.setDragEnabled(true)
t.enableEventsP(java.awt.AWTEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL_EVENT_MASK)

val f = new JFrame
f.getContentPane.add(new JScrollPane(t), java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER)
f.pack()
f.setVisible(true)
```

When I scroll the wheel while dragging and then release the mouse, the wheel events are delivered.

---

You may want to override the autoscroll behaviour of the `JTable` to make it faster, I guess. This is done in `DropTarget` as far as I can see. I found [this example](http://www.applettalk.com/fixing-drag-and-drop-autoscroll-for-jtree-jscrollpane-in-s-vt10399.html).

Comment: Thanks.  In my environment (ubuntu 12.04 + Open JDK 7), wheel events while dragging seem to be discarded.  Adjusting autoscroll behavior is good idea, but I afraid it confuses users who are accustomed to the default speed.